# xindy could not find file "lang/english/utf8-lang.xdy" despite being available

Tags: glossaries, indexing, xindy, glossaries-extra, perl

I get a strange error upon running

`perl.exe \path\to\xindy.pl  -L english -C utf8 -I xindy -M "main" -t "main.alg" -o "main.acr" "main.acn"`

or equivalently,

`xindy.exe  -L english -C utf8 -I xindy -M "main" -t "main.alg" -o "main.acr" "main.acn"`

The console output showing the error message is as follows

> Opening logfile "main.alg" (done)
>
> Reading indexstyle...
>
> Loading module
>
> "C:\\Documents\\phd_thesis\\1htZ_vspxV"...
>
> Error in line 1:
>
> (require "lang/english/utf8-lang.xdy")
>
> ERROR: Could not find file "lang/english/utf8-lang.xdy" !

Why am I getting this error, and how do I fix it?

### Update (Temporary Workaround)

This looks like a `xindy` bug. The required `.sty` file was already present in the folder `%TEXDIR%\texmf-dist\xindy\modules\lang\english\`, but was not found (and therefore not loaded) by `xindy`. To get this to work, I had to do two thngs

- copy the contents & structure of the `lang\english` tree into my project's root directory.
- copy the `tex.xdy` file from `%TEXDIR%\texmf-dist\xindy\modules\base\` also to my project's root directory.

Can a TeX expert here look into this and advise me on what is going on?

### Minimal example to reproduce the issue `(main.tex)`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[nomain,acronym,xindy]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries
\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{nohyperfirst}{true}
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short} % applicable only for glossaries-extra.sty
\newacronym{adc}{ADC}{Analog to Digital Converter}


\begin{document}

\cleardoublepage
\printglossary[type=acronym,title={List of Acronyms}]\label{ch:glossary} % basic style

This is some random text which uses \glspl{adc}.

\end{document}
```

Now, run

```
pdflatex main.tex
makeglossties main    (fails)
pdflatex main.tex     (redundant here since makeglossaries has failed. But required to print glossaries in the PDF once step 2 works.)
```

Also, I can confirmed that my aforesaid workaround (copying the `xindy` language tree as well as `tex.xdy` to this folder) is valid for this minimal example.

#### Environment

- Windows 10 64-bit (v1709, build 16299.846)
- pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018/W32TeX)
- xindy release: 2.5.1
- xindy.pl script version: 1.18
- Strawberry perl v5.28.1 built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread
- Makeglossaries Version 4.41 (2018-07-23)

#### TeXLive portable setup

The library machines in our university all run Windows 10. Obviously, students do not have admin access to install software. To workaround this, and to have a reproducible working environment, I keep all my favourite utilities and other tools on a network-mounted `Home drive`, labelled `H:` provided by the uni to all students. Each day I find myself on a different physical machine, but this is not a problem since the network drive gets mounted automatically upon login.  Therefore, I have set up a portable TeXlive whose environment variables are setup by running the following `batch script` at each login.

```
setx path "H:\username\texlive\2018\bin\win32;H:\username\perl-portable\perl\bin;"    
setx TEXDIR "H:\username\texlive\2018"
setx TEXMFLOCAL "H:\username\texlive\texmf-local"
setx TEXMFSYSVAR "H:\username\texlive\2018\texmf-var"
setx TEXMFSYSCONFIG "H:\username\texlive\2018\texmf-config"
setx TEXMFHOME "H:\username\texlive\texmf-local"
setx TEXMFDIST "H:\username\texlive\2018\texmf-dist"
setx TEXMFVAR "H:\username\texlive\2018\texmf-var"
setx TEXMFCONFIG "H:\username\texlive\2018\texmf-config"
setx TEXMFCACHE "H:\username\texlive\2018\texmf-var"
setx TEXLIVE_WINDOWS_TRY_EXTERNAL_PERL "1"
```

where `username` is my username using which I login to all university public computers.

Note:

One of the folks who commented below said that my minimal example worked fine for them and did not give any errors. So I wonder if the issue is related to this portable setup?

Comment: `perl xindy.pl` looks odd. In which directory are you when calling this command? And why aren't you calling xindy.exe?

Comment: @Ulrike that's exactly what `makeglossaries` calls behind the scenes. Instead of `xindy.pl`, it provides the full path to `xindy.pl`. Is there a way to instruct makeglossariez to directly use the `exe` when on Windows and switch appropriately when on Linux?

Comment: Sorry but it is quite a difference if you do `perl xindy` or `perl path/to/xindy`. So what are you doing really? And did you check if the missing file is in `...\texmf-dist\xindy\modules\lang\english`?

Comment: @KJO that's from 2013 and it is on ubuntu. Krishna has a texlive 2018 on windows.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer my bad I did not read question fully and see the windows reference I will delete comment as very misleading

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Merry Xmas. Please see my updates to my original question. The required `.sty` file was already present in the correct folder, but strangely was not detected by `xindy`. This looks like a `xindy` bug, isn't it?

Comment: Well you didn't provide a minimal example so I couldn't reproduce your steps, but in a small test with an index xindy found the xdy-file without problems.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you for the prompt. I have now provided a minimal example to reproduce the issue. I also included all the version details of my working environment.

Comment: Works fine for me. makeglossaries calls `xindy  -L english -C utf8 -I xindy -M "test-utf8" ... ` and finds the module without problems.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Alright. Something is different between your setup and mine. I have a portable `TeXLive` setup. Could that be the problem? I shall update the question with the details of my texlive setup.

Comment: Path settings for Perl and TeX Live should be ok but can be cumulative thus may exceed the path length. Also I think xindy package also likes some other TeXenv variables such as XINDY_SEARCHPATH A list of directories where the xindy modules are searched in. No subtree searching is done (as in
TDS-conformant TeX). see documentation

Comment: @KJO I have tried setting XINDY_SEARCH_PATH, but to no avail

Comment: @Krishna: Try by removing all new defined environment variables
except for the PATH.

Comment: Note it is XINDY_SEARCHPATH **not** XINDY_SEARCH_PATH

Answer (score 1):

In order to run from the command line an additional search variable needs to be set (it is NOT recursive so in this case it needs several;locations)

```
Set XINDY_SEARCHPATH=H:\username\texlive\2018\texmf-dist\xindy\modules;H:\username\texlive\2018\texmf-dist\xindy\modules\base
```

or for portable use after TEXMFDIST is set

```
Set XINDY_SEARCHPATH=%TEXMFDIST%\xindy\modules;%TEXMFDIST%\xindy\modules\base
```

then the following should work as it did for me

> pdfLaTeX main
>   makeglossaries main
>   pdfLaTeX main

Comment: still does not work for me

Comment: I am using portable but my directories are different so to check yours At a command prompt enter **where /r h:\ tex.xdy** based on my experience you should get H:\username\texlive\2018\texmf-dist\xindy\modules\base hence my suggested setting for search path